# can't quite figure out what's not working (checkio excersise "Even the Last")

Tags: python, arrays

*You are given an array of integers. You should find the sum of the integers with even indexes (0th, 2nd, 4th...). Then multiply this summed number and the final element of the array together. Don't forget that the first element has an index of 0.
For an empty array, the result will always be 0 (zero).
Input: A list of integers.
Output: The number as an integer.
Precondition: 0 ≤ len(array) ≤ 20
all(isinstance(x, int) for x in array)
all(-100 < x < 100 for x in array*

````
    result = 0 
    if array:
        for element in array: 
            i = array.index(element)
            if i%2 == 0:
                result += element
            else:
                pass
    else:
        return 0
        return result
    Last_digit = array[-1]
    final_result = result*Last_digit
    return final_result
    print(final_result)```
````

Comment: What is the error you're getting ? Your code should return the result although not very efficient. And have you put the code inside a function ? If you're just executing the code as you've written it here, then it won't work. `return` works only inside a function

Comment: this program cannot pass the last test on the checkio website, when you're given this specific array of numbers ''-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41'' - it's supposed to return 1968, but somehow returns -1476

Comment: Please check my answer, the problem is being caused by repeating value of 84 in your list and when you use `.index` it returns the index as 9 and not 16 thereby completely missing the value of 84

Comment: @Mistann please mark one of the answers correct if it solved your issue; this helps keep stackoverflow a place where everyone can get answers and learn from those which have already been solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem, that you've shared the array you're having problem with. Since you have this array :

> [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]

If you notice here, 84 appears twice, first at index 9 and then 16. The method you're using to get index of elements, `.index` returns the index of the first instance the element is found in the list.Therefore for the value of 84, the index is taken as 9 and not 16 which is an odd value, this does not add 84 to your sum. You should rather use `enumerate` for your code:

```
for idx, element in enumerate(array):             
        if idx %2 == 0:
            result += element
```

Comment: While this is one problem with the example code OP posted, it doesn't address the multiple other (and more serious) errors. As posted, even if you define dummy variables so `if array:` executes at all, you'll still get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on line 11. You should only post an answer that actually answers the question; if you're just fixing one of multiple issues with the code, you should leave it as a comment instead.

Comment: @W.MacTurk OP wasn't asking for lessons on 'Best Practises to Write Code'. Her code works even with the dangling `return` statement and the `else` block. Please run the code and check. OP just asked why the code was working with other arrays and not this particular array. I really appreciate how you have taken the effort to put a detailed answer with a cleaner code for OP, but if you see, your answer didn't solve OP's problem before you edited it to add the code I had already stated in my answer. And I had to add a code snippet in my answer which I couldn't do as a comment, else I would have.

Comment: Check the edit history. My original answer included your post almost verbatim, 6 or 7 minutes before you answered. Also, as posted, the OP's code doesn't run. It throws a SyntaxError. I realize he didn't ask for best practices; but they're there for a reason -- because they help others understand what the hell you're talking about. The question *should* have just been removed for not following the site's own guidelines for how to ask a question. Instead, I provided a solution and gave advice on how to ask better questions and write better code.

Comment: @W.MacTurk I'm not accusing you of copying my code. Apologies if you thought so. I'm just saying I appreciate your answer and your effort. I'll even go ahead and upvote your answer. Although I ran the code in VSCode  and it ran without throwing any errors. However, I concur that its not the best written code. All I am saying is, I just pointed out the specific part that was causing the issue with OP's code. And I would have commented it if I didn't have to write the code which involved multiple lines. And if you look at my comment on OP's question, I mentioned that it is not an efficient code.

Comment: Apologies if I came off aggressively -- I misinterpreted your tone before. Interesting that it runs fine in vscode -- both Hydrogen and the python CLI throw a syntax error.  And you're right; you did point out that it was inefficient. I missed that. When I saw the first line asking for a specific error OP was getting, I assumed I knew the gist of the rest of the comment so I just skipped to reading the next one -- that's my bad. If your answer solves the problem in VSCode, I'll upvote yours as well. I don't use VSCode and can't install it on this work computer, so I can't check myself. Cheers!

Comment: Oops, I'm at my daily vote limit. Will try to remember to circle back and upvote when its reset :)

Comment: @W.MacTurk I perfectly understand. Thanks, I'm so glad there are no hard feelings . Cheers :)

Comment: Hello there, sorry for replying late. thank you all so much for your help, your advice was in fact wery useful! I'll be more careful with forming my requests in the future,so it'll be clear what the problem is. (Also i saw one of the most polite arguments of my life,here, in the comments) :)  Im not sure how to edit the post for it to be marked as already answered, but i'll deal with it as soon as possible. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend reading the stackexchange guides on posting a well-formed question. You need to state what your goal is, what you've tried, what errors get thrown, and what the output should look like -- along with code examples and a minimal reproducible example as needed.

However, I'll help you out anyway.

You have a dangling `return` at line 11:

```
else:
    return 0
    return result
```

This makes no sense, as you've already returned `0`. This is also apparently a snippet from a function, no? Post the whole function. But based on the  instructions, you could try this:

```
import random

array = random.sample(range(-100, 100), 20)

def etl_func(arr):
    arrsum = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        if i%2 == 0: arrsum += val
    return (arrsum * arr[-1])
    
answer = etl_func(array)
print(answer)
```

Note that importing `random` and using `array = random.sample(range(-100, 100), 20)` are not necessary if you're already GIVEN an array to work with. They're included here just as an example.

Also note that it's unnecessary to use an `else: pass`. If the condition evaluates to true (i.e. `i%2 == 0`), the `if` block will be executed. If `i%2 != 0`, the loop will short circuit automatically and move to the next iteration. Adding `else: pass` is like telling someone sitting in your chair to sit in your chair. You're telling the program to do *what it's already going to do anyway*. There's nothing necessarily *wrong* with including the `else: pass`, if it really want to... but it's just adding lines of meaningless code, which nobody wants to deal with.

*EDIT:* I don't know whether you were supposed to write a function or just some code (back to the "ask a well-formed question" issue...), so I went with a function. It should be trivial to turn the function into just plain code -- but you want to get into the habit of writing good functions for reusability and modularity. Makes everything run more smoothly and elegantly, and makes troubleshooting much easier.

This function also works for the array mentioned in the comments to your original post.

In addition, if you need a direct replacement for your code (rather than a function... I'm not familiar with checkio or how your answers are supposed to be formatted), and you already have the array of integers stored in the variable `array`, try this:

```
arrsum = 0
for i, val in enumerate(array):
    if i%2 == 0: arrsum += val
print(arrsum * array[-1])
```

Since your question didn't say anything about using or defining functions, `return` statements shouldn't appear anywhere. There's nothing to return unless you're writing a function.